# Dynamically allocate or waste memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a 2d integer array used for a tile map.

The size of the map is unknown and read in from a file at runtime. currently the biggest file is 2500 items(50x50 grid).

I have a working method of dynamic memory allocation from an earlier question but people keep saying that it a bad idea so I have been thinking whether or not to just use a big array and not fill it all up when using a smaller map.

Do people know of any pros or cons to either solution ? any advice or personal opinions welcome.

c++ btw

edit: all the maps are made by me so I can pick a max size.

Comment: any reason you can't use the STL to maintain your arrays to save yourself the headaches of dynamically allocating the arrays yourself?

Comment: @Doug T which bit of the STL are you talking about. I thought about using an vector but as the array is filled completely at once and the only time it is edited is with a new map which would replace all the data.

Comment: Re: edit - even if they're all made by you what stops someone malicious sending one to your users which deliberately overflows and exploits a fixed size later on?

Comment: @awoodland getting off topic buy what would be the point of someone doing that be? I don't see the purpose of it ?

Comment: @Skeith, something like Mark B's answer would work

Comment: If it was possible to overflow by loading a 3rd party map someone evil could probably use it to execute any code they fancied just by trying to play a specially crafted map. That would be useful to steal secrets and plant malware.

Comment: @awoodland lol  I never thought of my code being worth stealing or having any secrets.

Comment: @Skeith - it's not stealing your code so much as stealing any secrets/data on any computer running your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be to dynamically allocate. That way should you encounter a surprisingly large map you (hopefully) won't overflow if you've written it correctly, whereas with the fixed size your only option is to return an error and fail.

Presumably loading tile maps is  a pretty infrequent operation. I'd be willing to bet too that you can't even measure a meaningful difference in speed between the two. Unless there is a measurable performance reduction, or you're actually hitting something else which is causing you problems the static sized one seems like a premature optimisation and is asking for trouble later on.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the easiest way is for example a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` to allow it to be dynamically sized AND let the library do all the allocations for you. This will prevent accidentally leaking memory.

Comment: +1, STL containers trumps getting hands dirty with arrays any day!

Comment: Since he can guess the size of the vector from the file size he should use the vector reserve() method to prevent a lot of time wasted on reallocations.

Comment: @Jay - reserving space for a 50x50 might well be the best of both worlds!

Comment: Doesn't need reserve: use vector's iterator range constructor instead.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on requirements that you haven't stated :-)

- If you want your app to be as blazingly fast as possible, with no ability to handle larger tile maps, then by all means just use a big array. For small PIC-based embedded systems this could be an ideal approach.
- But, if you want your code to be robust, extensible, maintainable and generally suitable for a wider audience, use STL containers.
- Or, if you just want to learn stuff, and have no concern about maintainability or performance, try and write your own dynamically allocating containers from scratch.

Comment: I am somewhat interested in performance as there is more than the map to load when the player moved between areas and I wanted the loading screen to be under 2 seconds if possible but I was more interested in whether the "saved" memory was worth the problems dynamic allocation creates ?

Comment: @Skeith Just remember that compared to the actual file I/O any of these options will be effectively equally fast.

Comment: @SKeith: Don't worry about "dynamic memory problems" unless you see them. And you won't.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue people refer to with dynamic allocation results from allocating randomly sized blocks of memory and not being able to effectively manage the random sized holes left when deallocated. If you're allocating fixed sized tiles then this may not be an issue.

I see quite a few people suggest allocating a large block of memory and managing it themselves. That might be an alternative solution.

Comment: With an STL based solution you can start out using std::vector and then change allocators *if* memory fragmentation really is a problem. Doing it otherwise at the early stages just seems like needless grief though.

Answer (score 1):

Is allocating the memory dynamically a bottleneck in your program? Is it the cause of a performance issue? If not, then simply keep dynamic allocation, you can handle any map size. If yes, then maybe use some data structure that does not deallocate the memory it has allocated but rather use its old buffer and if needed, reallocate more memory.